# How to add category and subcategory in WordPress custom code?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, categories, woocommerce-offtopic

I create custom plugin for import categories. now i have categories array from api.but when import categories into my wordpress woo commerce means not working.

My code is given below.

```
public function sample_insert_category() {
    if(!term_exists('sample-category')) {
        wp_insert_term(
            'Sample Category',
            'category',
            array(
              'description' => 'This is an sample category.',
              'slug'        => 'sample-category'
            )
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'sample_insert_category' );
```

already i have used this code in function.php file. now i create a plugin. so i need to include this to my plugin. 
When i add this code into my plugin class means i got the warning.

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'admin_menu_top' not found or invalid function name
```

i want to add category and sub category using code.. help me anyone.

Comment: Error seems be in another place and not in the code you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i used the following code and i add category from my plug in.

```
class MyPluginClass {
    public function __construct() {
         add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'sample_insert_category') );
    }


    public function sample_insert_category() {


        if(!term_exists('Test','product_cat')) {

            wp_insert_term(
                'Test',
                'product_cat',
                array(
                    'description' => 'This is an sample category.',
                    'slug'        => 'Test'
                )
            );
        }

    }


}

$mypluginclass = new MyPluginClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for adding an action in WordPress WITHIN a class is somewhat different.  Your code will have to look somewhat more like the following...

```
class MyPluginClass {

    public function __construct() {

         add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'sample_insert_category') );
    }

    public function sample_insert_category() {

        if(!term_exists('sample-category')) {
            wp_insert_term(
                'Sample Category',
                'category',
                array(
                    'description' => 'This is an sample category.',
                    'slug'        => 'sample-category'
                )
            );
        }

    }
}

$mypluginclass = new MyPluginClass();
```

Comment: my condition always false on if(!term_exists('sample-category')) in this line. so i have removed this condition. but its not working for me..